# Incrementing a Count column by clicking a Checkbox column in a DataGridView

Tags: c#, checkbox, gridview, cell

The problem is I have a lot of rows in gridview but when I checked a certain or any Checkbox, I wasn't able to add 1 in count column.

I just need a code that whenever in any row of gridview I check a specific checkbox it will automatically add 1 to corresponding count value

```cs
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    // Check if the clicked cell is in the "Attendance" column
    if (e.RowIndex >= 0 && e.ColumnIndex == dataGridView1.Columns["Attendance"].Index)
    {
        // Toggle the "Attendance" value in the "Attend" column
        DataGridViewCheckBoxCell checkBoxCell = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex] as DataGridViewCheckBoxCell;

        if (checkBoxCell != null) // Check if the cell exists
        {
            // Get the current value of the "Attend" cell (assuming it contains numeric data)
            int currentAttendance = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Attend"].Value);

            // Toggle the value between "1" and "0" when the checkbox is clicked
            int newAttendance = (currentAttendance == 0) ? 1 : 0;

            // Update the "Attend" cell with the new value
            dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Attend"].Value = newAttendance;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "I wasn't able to add 1 in count column"? This code does not add 1 anywhere.

Comment: Sir then provide me a code that does this ...

Answer (score 0):

I tried to simplify the code a little bit by using a local variable for the cells collection and by using pattern matching.

Assuming that you have a column named "Count", we can add the lines

```cs
int count = Convert.ToInt32(cells["Count"].Value);
cells["Count"].Value = count + 1;
```

Together:

```cs
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    // Check if the clicked cell is in the "Attendance" column
    if (e.RowIndex >= 0 && e.ColumnIndex == dataGridView1.Columns["Attendance"].Index)
    {
        var cells = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells;

        // Toggle the "Attendance" value in the "Attend" column
        if (cells[e.ColumnIndex] is DataGridViewCheckBoxCell checkBoxCell) // Check if the cell exists
        {
            // Get the current value of the "Attend" cell (assuming it contains numeric data)
            int currentAttendance = Convert.ToInt32(cells["Attend"].Value);

            // Toggle the value between "1" and "0" when the checkbox is clicked
            int newAttendance = (currentAttendance == 0) ? 1 : 0;

            // Update the "Attend" cell with the new value
            cells["Attend"].Value = newAttendance;

            // Increase Count
            int count = Convert.ToInt32(cells["Count"].Value);
            cells["Count"].Value = count + 1;
        }
    }
}
```

But is is easier to use a class to model you data by implementing the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface and to bind the GridView to this model. By making `Attend` a boolean property, the CheckBox will update this property automatically (without code). Then you can simply make the changes in the model (e.g. increase `Count`). Or you can even implement this logic in the model class and let the `Attend` property update the `Count` property. Then you can drop this Click method.

Comment: I tried multiple times but all I have is ... a error.if (e.ColumnIndex == dataGridViewAttendance.Columns["Attendance"].Index)
 object reference not set to an instant of an object

Comment: Each and everything will run smoothly but it I'll definitely generate this error.if (e.ColumnIndex == dataGridViewAttendance.Columns["Attendance"].Index)

Object reference not set to an instant of an object

Comment: Well, then the cell's name is probably not "Attendance". Btw., have you renamed `dataGridView1` to `dataGridViewAttendance`?

Comment: I does this as well... sir

Comment: I think It's just  because I just try to access an object that is null.

Comment: if you write `dataGridViewAttendance.Columns["Attendance"]` and a column named like this does not exist, then this will return `null`. If then you try to access `.Index` this throws this exception.

Comment: Ok sir got it... I'll try it and then I'll consult it with you... thanks sir